# INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged fired, but UI not updated after form loads

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Below is an example of my model , `ViewModel` and xaml binding.  The viewmodel implements `INotifyPropertChanged`. The problem i'm having is...when the wpf form first loads i set `ActiveStock` and i see both setter and getter being called and the ui is updated to reflect the data correctly.
However, when i later set `StockViewModel.ActiveStoc`k, `FirePropertyChanged` is invoked but i don't see the getter being called, and consequently the UI does not update to reflect the new data.  Any ideas what might be happening here?

The second question i have is whether i also need to raise `PropertyChanged` for the child properties (`PriceData` and `CompanyData`) of my model when `ViewModel.ActiveStock` is changed?

```
public class Stock
{
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public StockData PriceData { get; set; }
    public StockData CompanyData { get; set; }
}
public class StockData
{
    ...
}
public class StockViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Stock _activeStock;
    public Stock ActiveStock
    {
        get{ return _activeStock;}
        set{ _activeStock = value; FirePropertyChanged("ActiveStock");}
    }
    ...
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl Template="{StaticResource StockTemplate}" DataContext="{Binding ActiveStock}" Tag="{Binding PriceData}" />
<UserControl Template="{StaticResource StockTemplate}" DataContext="{Binding ActiveStock}" Tag="{Binding CompanyData}" />
```

Edit:
if i remove the DataContext binding for the UserControl and instead set the DataContext for these two controls in code behind when ActiveStock changes, it works fine.  why???

Comment: Show us your codebehind of the view so we can see how you are binding your ViewModel and setting the data in ActiveStock.

Comment: 1) It would be helpful to see the xaml for the StockTemplate. 2) Do you set the View's DataContext before or after InitializeComponent()?

Comment: After...the problem turned out to be typo in FirePropertyChanged argument! geez...i wish there was a better way (without reflection) to deal with InotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 4):

The getter is not being called because as far as I can see nothing is "getting" the value, The only properties used are `PriceData` and `CompanyData` and these don't use `INotifyPropertyChanged`

You will have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `Stock` class for the `UI` to reflect the changes.

```
public class Stock : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _ticker;
    private StockData _priceData;
    private StockData _companyData;

    public string Ticker
    {
        get { return _ticker; }
        set { _ticker = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Ticker"); }
    }

    public StockData PriceData
    {
        get { return _priceData; }
        set { _priceData = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("PriceData"); }
    }


    public StockData CompanyData
    {
        get { return _companyData; }
        set { _companyData = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("CompanyData"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i implement INotifyPropertyChanged on these classes, something still has to fire NotifyPropertyChanged in order for a uielement to know that it needs to go get something...so you're saying that the ViewModel class will have to fire these events, even though the only property it concerns itself with is its own ActiceStock property?

Comment: I think your answer was the closest.  the problem was not that i needed to fire events for the member properties (which i was doing already), it was a typo in the FirePropertyChanged args.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try to specify the mode property on your datacontext bindings.

```
DataContext="{Binding ActiveStock, Mode=OneWay}"
```

I'm not sure that OneTime is the default binding for DataContext, but it would explain so if the above helps.

The second question has been answered by sa_ddam213.

HTH

Comment: What sets the datacontext of your xaml file?

Comment: in the form, i have a public member
   "public StockViewModel ViewModel {get; set;}"

I create and assign an instance of StockViewmOdel to it in the constructor of the form and then assign DataContext = ViewModel

Comment: Try doing that in the Loaded event like so:

 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }
        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel = new StockViewModel();
            DataContext = ViewModel;
        }

Comment: that did not work either.  the only thing that is working is removing the binding to ActiveStock from the xaml and explicitly setting the DataContext of the user control in code behind.  i just don't get it.

Comment: Try replacing the <UserControl> with <ContentControl>
That works for me. (Your StockTemplate should become a <ContentControlTemplate> of course).

Comment: Actually I cannot reproduce this. Could you have a look to see what I did and if that is of any help to you? http://sdrv.ms/Xj0lde

Comment: 1 up for trying to help.  it was totally my fault.